# I want to make a table in mysql using python and i get this error but i have data base named sam what should i do

Tags: python, mysql, database

```py
import pymysql as ps

con = ps.connect('localhost','root','','sam') #connecting to the database

print("connected ! ! !")
c = con.cursor() #were are we in database

com="""create table u(
        code int PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar(20),
        family varchar(20),
        age int(3)) """


c.execute(com)
con.commit()

con.close()
```

> [Exception has occurred: OperationalError
> (1049, "Unknown database 'sam'")
> File "E:\script\python mySQL\making_new_sql.py", line 3, in 
> con = pymysql.connect('localhost','root','','sam') #connecting to the database]

Comment: Your database `sam` has not been created yet, create it first.Btw, highlight the code, otherwise the readability is poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the database with the same name as `sam` in order to access it through python. Use the MYSQL console that came with your installation to create the database.
use the command:

```
CREATE DATABASE sam
```

Then you can go ahead and add the table through python.